# Keyboard not work suddenly

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard work in ubuntu but suddenly  is not working in Ubuntu ever.what should I do?
Thank for your advice

Comment: Simple trouble shoot, try other keyboard,hoping you already tried restarting the machiune. If the other keyboard works then the current one is dead, else add more details to your question.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i try other keyboard but it didnt work too.